# Thread not executing

Tags: java, multithreading

This thread does not execute when I run the program. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the code.

```
public static void writeToFileAsync(final String saveState, final String fileName)  {    
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                writeToFile(saveState, fileName);
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            start();
        }
    };
}
```

Also, why does NetBeans want me to put that semicolon next to the second curly brace after the `start()` call?

Comment: You have to call `start` after you created the Thread-Object. Look at some thread-examples on the Internet!

Comment: You're not starting your thread.

Comment: Why should it run? You need to call the `start` method on the `Thread`. Take a look at the documentation [Thread#start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--)

Comment: *Also, why does NetBeans want me to put that semicolon next to the second curly brace after the start() call?* Because `new Thread() { ... };` is a statement.

Answer (score 3):

### Start a thread

Your thread will only start if you call the `start` method **explicitly**. Here is the documentation [Thread#start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--). The `start` method will then internally invoke the `run` method of your `Thread`.

Your code could then look like this:

```
public static void writeToFileAsync(final String saveState, final String fileName)  {
    // Create the thread
    Thread fileWriter = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                writeToFile(saveState, fileName);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    };

    // Start the thread
    fileWriter.start();
}
```

And you probably want to remove the `start();` call inside your `run` method.

---

### Semicolon

You need the `;` after the `Thread` creation because you are using an assignment:

```
Thread fileWriter = new Thread() { ... };
```

The concept you are using here is called **anonymous class**. Basically it is the same as if creating a new class like:

```
public class FileWriter extends Thread  {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then using it like:

```
Thread fileWriter = new FileWriter();
```

However an important difference is that your anonymous class has access to your local variables (the scope of that method). And that it is **anonymous**, so it's like a small single-time usage class.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to the `start` method cannot be inside the body of your thread. You can do this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            writeToFile(saveState, fileName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
}.start(); // call the start method outside the body of you thread.
```

And about the semicolon, you are creating an Anonymous Class and that is its [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes):

> *Because an anonymous class definition is an expression, it must be
>   part of a statement... (This explains why there is a semicolon after
>   the closing brace.)*

Comment: @Mike2 please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

A thread simply works this way. Below is a piece of code where a thread is created as an anonymous inner type where the run method is overrided. Then by calling the start method , it automatically called the overrided run method.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("thread is  running");
        };
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest();
        threadTest.t.start();
    }
}
```